# Applying a function to different levels of a factor in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with 30 variables and ~6000 rows. The variable 'chart number' identifies each subject and each subject has repeated measurments over time. So there are ~500 unique 'chart numbers' but since these subjects came in multiple time, we have ~6000 observations.

Now, I need to impute height data for each subject by using the subjects average height of the visits. How do I apply a function to each level of the chart number i.e, to each subject?

Right now, I am creating a list and storing each subject's visits as its own data frame in the list and then running a loop over all the elements(data frames) of the lists.

How do I apply a function to each level of the chart number without creating a list?

Comment: Take a look at tapply

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for specific programming questions. Can you provide a clear example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: And it sounds like you want to a) split your data set by chart number b) apply an imputation function to each split and c) combine the result. The **dplyr** package is perfect for this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html

Comment: Do you want to apply a mean function over hieght by chart number? If so, you should look at the `aggregate` function or the `data.table` equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `ave` the function to run a method across over factor levels. Specifically, for you include `ave()` within `ifelse` to keep non-missing heights and replace missing height values:

```
df$imp_visit_height <- ifelse(is.na(df$visit_height), 
                              ave(df$visit_height, df$chart_number, 
                                  FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)), 
                              df$visit_height)
```

Or less wordy equivalent using `within()`

```
df <- within(df, imp_visit_height <- ifelse(is.na(visit_height), 
                                            ave(visit_height, chart_number, 
                                                FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)), 
                                            visit_height))
```

To demonstrate with random data where *chart_number* covers computing languages/packages:

```
set.seed(43018)  # SEEDED FOR REPRODUCIBILITY

grp <- c("julia", "r", "pandas", "sas", "stata", "spss")

df <- data.frame(
  chart_number = replicate(100, sample(grp, 1, replace=TRUE)),
  time = as.Date(replicate(100, Sys.Date() - sample(1:120, 1, replace=TRUE)), 
                 origin="1970-01-01"),
  visit_height = rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=5),
  measurement = rnorm(100)*100
)

# RANDOMLY ASSIGN 25 ROWS WITH NA TO visit_height
df[sample(1:100, 25, replace=TRUE), c("visit_height")] <- NA

# CONDITIONALLY IMPUTE MISSING VALUES
df$imp_visit_height <- ifelse(is.na(df$visit_height), 
                              ave(df$visit_height, df$chart_number, 
                                  FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)), 
                              df$visit_height)
```

**Output** *(filtering to missing visit_height)*

```
df[is.na(df$visit_height),]

#    chart_number       time visit_height measurement imp_visit_height
# 4           sas 2018-02-03           NA -116.072314         49.77708
# 6          spss 2018-04-02           NA   33.049215         52.05987
# 12        julia 2018-01-14           NA  135.954163         52.49936
# 14       pandas 2018-04-09           NA  -92.215212         49.23258
# 19         spss 2018-01-21           NA  -43.422507         52.05987
# 27        julia 2018-03-18           NA  -46.679790         52.49936
# 45       pandas 2018-03-19           NA -181.014747         49.23258
# 48        stata 2018-02-22           NA  -89.135797         51.12526
# 51         spss 2018-01-24           NA    9.784664         52.05987
# 53       pandas 2018-04-23           NA  106.461095         49.23258
# 55       pandas 2018-02-17           NA  121.749821         49.23258
# 58        julia 2018-01-19           NA -151.584425         52.49936
# 65       pandas 2018-03-04           NA -148.877957         49.23258
# 70            r 2018-01-05           NA   83.888427         49.29048
# 71          sas 2018-02-21           NA -213.640525         49.77708
# 73        julia 2018-04-18           NA  181.791644         52.49936
# 79            r 2018-03-09           NA   -4.446414         49.29048
# 82       pandas 2018-02-20           NA   28.069077         49.23258
# 84        julia 2018-02-27           NA   16.468641         52.49936
# 85         spss 2017-12-31           NA -106.316136         52.05987
# 86            r 2018-02-26           NA    1.450771         49.29048
# 91         spss 2018-04-05           NA  -34.662075         52.05987
# 93            r 2018-03-03           NA   36.777125         49.29048
# 95        julia 2018-01-20           NA  -36.827340         52.49936
# 98        julia 2017-12-31           NA  125.342483         52.49936
```